# Openvpn, two tap network adapters

Tags: networking, openvpn, tap, adapter

I have installed openvpn client on my pc (windows 7) and I have two tap network adapters. In this way I can open two openvpn connections at the same time. What I would like to understand is how it's decided each connection I open which tap adapter will be chosen. The first available network adapter is chosen or some other logic exists?

Answer (score 0):

The OS will choose the route (and thus interface) with the [lowest metric](https://superuser.com/questions/198544/how-does-windows-7-decide-which-route-to-take-if-2-connections-to-an-internet-so). To tweak which interface is used you can [push a route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/openvpn-push-a-route-to-client-with-a-different-gateway) with a particular metric; for example

```
push route "10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1"
```

from the man page

```
--route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric]
```

Comment: And in the default case, with same metrics, i'm not sure which one wins. Maybe the first that appeared in the routing table.